# Stopping apache mina server

Tags: apache-mina

I have written a tcp server in Apache Mina.The server listens to a port n do the process. I have deployed this in jboss server. But now i am not able to stop the server.

I have done the following things for the stop program:

```
acceptor.dispose();
acceptor.unbind();
acceptor.setCloseOnDeactivation(true);
```

But the port is still active and the server still runs.

Can anybody help me in understanding how to stop the server.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Apache Mina Acceptor](https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch3-service/acceptor.html) service can be stopped and waiting for it using acceptor.dispose( true ). Also you can use isDisposing() method to verify that.

Comment: Is there any specific order that i need to follow.